# Finding which checkbox is clicked or checked in nested ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of parent check boxes with list of sub check boxes within each parent check box.

With parent check-box a data-info="category" attribute is attached and with child check-box a data-info="name" attribute is attached.

With check and uncheck of parent checkbox, list of sub checkboxes are visible and hidden respectively

What I want is that when I uncheck the parent checkbox, all subchkbx should also get unchecked. Only unchecked not for checked scenario.

Also, I want to access data-info attribute of checked checkbox. How can I get this attribute on check of a checkbox.

Currently I am achieving this with the help of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a checkbox to a checked property on the parent item, and then setup a `$watch`: when the checked property changes, update the children's checked property.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.parents = [
    { 
      name: 'parent1',
      checked: false,
      children: [{
        name: 'child1',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: 'child2',
        checked: false
      }]
    }];
  
    angular.forEach($scope.parents, function(item,index) {
      $scope.$watchCollection('parents[' + index + ']', function(newVal) {
          if (newVal) {
            angular.forEach(newVal.children, function(item, index) {
              item.checked = newVal.checked;
            });
          }
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="parent.checked" /> {{parent.name}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="child.checked" /> {{child.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually name of checkboxes are coming via ajax from server, so i can not put a checked field in my json.
Also forEach inside forEach is heavy, complexity vise and 
your code is also checking  all sub checkboxes on checking a parent checkbox.
Like juery is not there any kind of $('input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
only one line code so that i select all subcheck boxes inside a parent using jquery and set the checked attribute to false. This is only one line thing and much simpler

Comment: jquery vs angularjs and you're choosing to use jQuery... good luck:)

Comment: No i am not choosing jquery, it's just that i have to use jquery because i was not able to perform the thing which i wanted using angular and in jquery its was just a single line code.
i want to do that type of thing using angular and that's the whole point of posting my problem here.
please help or suggest me a good way